# Calculate Frequency In Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a start time and an end time and I am capturing that time in Hours.  I have the user inputting a target goal, and I want to know how often a basket must be made in order for the target goal to be hit.

For example, the `startTime = 08:00 AM` and the `endTime = 09:00 AM` and the `targetGoal = 5` simple math logic tells us that between 8 and 9 am is 1 hour or 60 minutes, so to hit the target goal of 5, the user must make at least 1 basket every 12 minutes (=60/5)

I have no issue with this logic, but in my VBA I can't quite get the logistics of it down.  This is what I have so far.

```
Dim sHour As Double
Dim eHour As Double
Dim targetMake As Double
Dim hitFreq As Double

targetMake = Sheets("Statistics").Range("C2").Value
sHour = Sheets("Statistics").Range("A2").Value
eHour = Sheets("Statistics").Range("B2").Value

hitFreq = (eHour - sHour) / targetMake
```

and instead of returning 12 as expected when I run this VBA I get `4.166666666`

What is off in the calculation or declaration type?

Comment: What are your actual inputs in those cells? For example, is `startTime` 8, or 8:00 AM? Remember that 1 day is equivalent to `1` so if you want the result in hours or minutes you have to do the conversion mathematically.

Comment: sHour = 1/8/1900 8:00:00 AM, eHour = 1/8/1900 9:00:00 AM, and targetMake = 5

Comment: `hitFreq = (eHour - sHour) * 24 * 60 / targetMake`

Comment: With those inputs, i get `8.33333333333322E-03` as the output... (which if you multiply by 24 * 60 gets you the 12 minutes answer you're looking for, once you round).

Comment: so the ```*24``` is for 24 hours, and the ```*60``` is for 60 minutes, right? --- and yes that resolved it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the data and data formatting within your sheet.

In this case it appears that the field is formatted to display hours and, when it display general date and hours there is a concrete number behind the displayed info.

For example:

- If the cell is formatted to display hours and it is displaying 08:00AM there is a number behind that would be something like "8,333"
- when you use `Range("A2").Value` it returns "8,333" and not 8, as you would think

for the end time would be the same

- 09:00AM would be represented by something like "8,375".

That is what is going on in your program.

To fix it you would need to convert the retrieved value to the correspondig hour.

try the following conversion method:

```
sHour = Sheets("Statistics").Range("A2").Value
sConverted = (sHour - CInt(sHour)) * 24

eHour = Sheets("Statistics").Range("A2").Value
eConverted = (eHour - CInt(eHour)) * 24
```

you will also need to convert hour to minutes in the final formula

```
hitFreq = (eConverted - sConverted ) * 60 / targetMake
```

that should fix your problem

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim sHour As Date
Dim eHour As Date
Dim targetMake As Double
Dim hitFreq As Double

targetMake = Sheets("Statistics").Range("C2").Value
sHour = CDate(Sheets("Statistics").Range("A2").Value)
eHour = CDate(Sheets("Statistics").Range("B2").Value)

hitFreq = DateDiff("h", sHour, eHour) / targetMake
```

I have made three changes:

1. The variables sHour and eHour are changed to Date
2. There is a a `CDate` added to make sure that the dates are converted.
3. `DateDiff` is very good function to use when calculating time diffs

Perhaps inverting the hitFreq calc also?